# Math calculations "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" error message

Tags: python, concatenation, calculation

Working on trying to understand variables input strung together to get calculations done.
Checked on here for quite some time but could not find the answer specific to my problem or if I did I may not of been able to identify it. very new so any tips/advice/resources is incredibly appreciated. Below is the beginning of the code I was working on.

```
print('Hello there! Today we will be learning how to calculate your macros! ')
print(' We will start of by gathering some of your info valuable in the calculations.')
H = input('How tall are you in inches over the 5ft mark? ')
W = input('Now how much do you currently weight in pounds? ')
A = input('Now how many hours of activity would you say that you get per day? ')

c = sum((H + 105)*10+400)
d = sum (c / 4)
carbs = sum (d * 2)/4
```

Here is the error message I am receiving from this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ironv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HelloWorld\venv\app.py", line 7, in 
<module>
    c = sum((H + 19)*10)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

What is my formatting error?

Comment: This also won't work because the `sum` functions sums a iteratable (list) of numbers. You don't need that here.

Comment: Please try to looking for online free tutorials like datacamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input function returns a string. You must convert it to an integer if you want to use it as one.
Along with this, the sum function only works on iterables. Integers are not iterable, so using the sum function on one would cause the program to raise an error.

Your fixed code would look like this:

```py
H = int(input('How tall are you in inches over the 5ft mark? '))
W = int(input('Now how much do you currently weigh in pounds? '))
A = int(input('Now how many hours of activity would you say that you get per day? '))

c = (H + 105)*10+400
d = c / 4
carbs = d * 2/4
```

Comment: This gives ```TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable``` if you enter three integers

Comment: @Nin17 Why are you using the sum function? Ints are not iterable, so if you remove that it should work.

Comment: I was using the ```sum``` function because you wrote it

Comment: @Nin17, oh my bad, must have forgotten to remove it. Anyway, remove that and it should be good (check the new code in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `input()` will return you a `String` variable, your `H` will be a `String` type. You need to convert it to `int` type first before doing any arithmetic.

```py
H = input('How tall are you in inches over the 5ft mark? ')
print(type(H)) # <class 'str'>

H_int = int(H)
print(type(H_int)) # <class 'int'>
```